# How can I configure Worklight to serve *.svg files with contentType=image/xml+svg?

Tags: svg, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

When I try to use an svg file as the source for an image tag, or as a background image url, I don't see anything (and firebug tells me `Failed to load the given url`

It looks like it is because Worklight is serving it with a `Content-Type` response header of `application/octet-stream`. How can I get Worklight to send it with `image/svg+xml` so that it will display properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found it. Add the following to the server.xml:

```
<mimeTypes>
    <type>svg=image/svg+xml</type>
</mimeTypes>
```

[ You can open server.xml by going to the server view. Double click on your server to open the server overview, then under **Liberty Profile Settings**, click **Open server configuration** ]

Comment: Solved the same issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. I am trying the same thing with wlp8.5.5. I have css=text/css under <types>, but the css is still downloaded as text/html in chrome and firefox. Thank you !

Comment: @U-L: I have similar issue. How did you resolve that? I am using Liberty and css/js files are downloaded as text/html and browser blocks them to download as no-sniff is enabled for security reasons. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `<object>` tag instead of `<img>`

```
<object data="sample.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Comment: Tried this, also <embed> and <iframe> with no luck :-( ... also, this wouldn't help me with background images.