# worklight server preview wont show png resources anymore after configuring it to serve svg

Tags: svg, png, ibm-mobilefirst

I ran in the problem where svg images were not loading using WorkLight preview. I found the solution for that here: [How can I configure Worklight to serve *.svg files with contentType=image/xml+svg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748259/how-can-i-configure-worklight-to-serve-svg-files-with-contenttype-image-xmlsv)

After adding these lines

```
<mimeTypes>
    <type>svg=image/svg+xml</type>
</mimeTypes>
```

svg files appeared on preview, but now i can't load png files. Is there a way to make all the formats work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to add another `type` for .png then?

```
<mimeTypes>
    <type>svg=image/svg+xml</type>
    <type>png=image/png</type>
</mimeTypes>
```